# Bitlocker and Dropbox

Tags: encryption, dropbox, bitlocker

Im looking to enable bitlocker on my laptop.  I Use my laptop for work and I have it connected to a company shared dropbox folder.  As there is sensitive data in this dropbox older, Id like to enable bitlocker to secure my local copies of these files.

My question here is, will this encrypt the cloud stored copies of the files?  Im concerned about accidentally locking everyone else out of the files in the cloud stored dropbox if I use bitlocker to encrypt the local copies as dropbox syncs everything.

Comment: If you encrypt the entire drive, yes, what you upload will be encrypted

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think that is true. Bitlocker is full-disk encryption, that means it encrypts at low level (sectors). While Dropbox synchronizes at file level. It just reads data from files (even if they are encrypted physically on disk), just like any other application. So (unencrypted) content of files will be synced to cloud.

Comment: @ge0rdi - Easy enough to get around.  Mount and encrypt a .VHD and sync that to Dropbox.

Answer (score 5):

@ge0rdi's comment is correct -- the files are decrypted before Dropbox sees them, so Dropbox uploads only the decrypted files and no one else sharing the files will be affected.

Here's another reference on Microsoft's website: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/bitlocker-w-dropbox-box-and-outlook/9b82fe7b-9766-4d88-b377-61f1963e0f6d